Space is not reclaimed after ROLLBACK in postgres script
I have a postgres script that ran on an RDS instance using the psql tool in pgadmin:
BEGIN;

update table set mytimecolumn = 'this';
update table set mytimecolumn = 'that';
update table set mydatecolumn = 'this';
update table set mydatecolumn = 'that';

COMMIT;

I ran out of space in the middle of the script on the instance and ran ROLLBACK;
My space was not reclaimed even though the script definitely rolled back
Was expecting space to be reclaimed nearly immediately. Can someone explain why it was not reclaimed?

Does this answer your question? PostgreSQL - restored database smaller than original

Normal behavior, autovacuum makes the space available for new records. You might need VACUUM FULL when you really messed up things. That should be the rare exception.

You need to run vacuum full;
Because of MVCC, an update is really an insert that writes a whole new value and marks the old one as outdated. Only if you commit the operation and no other transaction is open with a snapshot of the old values, the space occupied by the old version of the row will be reclaimed by autovacuum, table rewrite or someone's manually issued vacuum.
Table pages that will get emptied entirely will be returned to the system, but without fully rewriting the table the empty space on any other page will be still assigned to the table and available for its exclusive use.

Thank you for the detailed explanation. So the new values still exists along with the old values even after the ROLLBACK;?

@ZachAnton Yes. Most file systems and file formats do that. When you remove something it's less expensive to mark it to be deleted later as a larger operation, rather than do it immediately. Some text files even stored inline backspace characters, while today an edit to a file means it gets appended with a line saying what changed, without actually editing anything in the body. Windows first puts things in the Recycle bin, only when they get removed from there also, marks them for actual deletion, and only after that it actually overwrites them when it needs more space.

So hypothetically, if I were to run the same script again now, would I see any decrease in space since the old & new values still exist? This is in a case where I have not run vacuum analyze on any tables and instead just increase my DB storage capacity

If there's no other transaction that's open an holding on to the old snapshot, following inserts and updates should be able to overwrite whatever you inserted/updated, then rolled back, or deleted/updated and committed. I think updates will prefer existing pages, while inserts will typically prefer new ones, which changes slightly if you tweak your fillfactor setting and/or cluster the table.
